# Why is Android time around 40 seconds behind Linux C time?

Tags: android, c, linux, time, epoch

In Android Studio,

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

returns a time that is around 40-43 seconds behind

```
time(NULL);
```

called on C in Linux.

Is this a problem of my machine or is it normal?

Comment: If the difference is 37 seconds, it might be that one clock is keeping UTC and one is keeping TAI, that is, without leap seconds.  (I doubt it, though.)

Comment: If Android is returning time in milliseconds, and `time()` is returning time in seconds, how are you comparing them?

Comment: @SteveSummit The difference is always 42-43 seconds, I execute both instructions less than a second from each other. I compare them by looking at the fifth and sixth digit of the time returned in Android, which would be the tens of seconds, and it's easy to see there is a ~40 second difference. I tested right now and I got 1627592004 on Linux and 1627591962658 on Android Studio, Linux is 42 seconds ahead.

Comment: Can you use a cell phone, or a GPS receiver, or some other accurate time source to determine which one of them is right?

Comment: Can you make sure you test both either on the host system or in the emulator, so that you're not comparing a virtual machine's clock to its host?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the underlying setup. Where the "android" clock is running? Where the Linux clock is running? Is Android running on an emulation?

Comment: Android is running on an emulation and the Linux virtual machine is the one that's right, I probably have to sync the time on the Android emulator

Comment: It's conceivable that the emulator supports having a different time than the host.

Comment: @ikegami shouldn't the epoch time be universal? I synced both the emulator and the linux vm with the network yet the difference remains

Comment: Re "*shouldn't the epoch time be universal?*", No, I can set my computer's clock to anything I want. I could set it to what I think is the current time (1627593219 aka 2021-07-29T17:13:39-04:00), or I could set it to be 40 seconds later (1627593259 aka 2021-07-29T17:14:19-04:00)  /// Re "*I synced both the emulator and the linux vm with the network yet the difference remains*",  No idea, then.

Comment: When you say you "synched both with the network", what does that mean?  Did you synch them both to the same NTP server?

Comment: Maybe move about 12 km east (or maybe west)  to adjust your computer's sundial reference? ;-)  See also [other time scales](http://leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm) and double-check [NTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582436/why-is-android-time-around-40-seconds-behind-linux-c-time#comment121205175_68582436).

Comment: I can think of a lot of reasons that the emulator and the hardware would be out of sync and have some constant difference. What strikes me as odd is that the clock offset apparently jitters between +/- 1.5 seconds. That is a lot.

Comment: @SteveSummit I set the date and time in the Linux settings and the Android settings using the network provided date and time both systems offer.

Comment: @outsidethecave I guess about all I can say is, time synchronization can be a surprisingly hard problem, for both theoretical and practical reasons.  It sounds like your Android side is not actually setting itself to the network time *correctly*.  There's unfortunately plenty of time-synchronization code out there that works very well when it works, but has agonizingly, frustratingly pathological failure modes under which it doesn't manage to synchronize time at all.  It sounds like that may be what's happening for you, because 40 seconds is clearly not an inconsequential error!

Comment: @outsidethecave The information that you have provided in the comments, please add it to the question proper (use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68582436/edit) link) and this has potential for becoming both a very interesting and an answerable question IMHO.